# Issue calling a variable in the state class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state-management

I want to trigger a boolean variable 'runBackdropBlur' in the state class as per below code.

To do this I want to be able to call the method turnOnBackdropBlur() (from another widget), and this method in turn, when called will change this variable in it's state class by use of global key.

I have been following this tutorial, to achieve a simple state management solution for this case:
[tutorial](https://flutteragency.com/call-method-in-one-stateful-widget/)

However, I run into these two errors in flutter, i cannot fix...
"Named parameters must be enclosed in curly braces ('{' and '}')."
"The default value of an optional parameter must be constant."

```
class Backdrop extends StatefulWidget {
  Backdrop(key : _myKey);

  GlobalKey<_BackdropState> _myKey = GlobalKey<_BackdropState>();
 void turnOnBackdropBlur() {
_myKey.currentState!.runBackdropBlur = true;
 }

  @override
  _BackdropState createState() => _BackdropState();
}

class _BackdropState extends State<Backdrop> {

  bool runBackdropBlur = false;

//etc
```

Comment: i would say move everything inside state class

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However,I cant move the above into the state class because then i cant call the method from another widget  (I cant also convert it to a state class because I need this to be a stateful widget for other purposes).

Answer (score 0):

With some tricks you can do everything you want. You can give a pointer of a method to the owner widget as follows:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Backdrop extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, Function> listener = new Map<String, Function>();

  void setnBackdropBlurTrue() => listener.containsKey("BackdropBlurTrue")
      ? listener["BackdropBlurTrue"].call()
      : log("BackdropBlurTrue key is null");

  void setnBackdropBlurFalse() => listener.containsKey("BackdropBlurFalse")
      ? listener["BackdropBlurFalse"].call()
      : log("BackdropBlurFalse key is null");

  @override
  _BackdropState createState() => _BackdropState();
}

class _BackdropState extends State<Backdrop> {
  bool runBackdropBlur = false;

  void setRunBackdropBlurTrue() => runBackdropBlur = true;
  void setRunBackdropBlurFalse() => runBackdropBlur = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  _BackdropState() {
    widget.listener.putIfAbsent("BackdropBlurTrue", () => setRunBackdropBlurTrue);
    widget.listener.putIfAbsent("BackdropBlurFalse", () => setRunBackdropBlurFalse);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! That looks like a really useful pattern to use. I have tried to implement this solution though (by calling "Backdrop backdrop = Backdrop(); backdrop.setnBackdropBlurTrue();" from another class but this only returns the null log, not sure if you know where I am going wrong? --Note: dart also gave me a null error here "listener["BackdropBlurTrue"].call()" so i added the "!" operator and changed to "listener["BackdropBlurTrue"]!.call()" and not sure if this is the source of the problem...?